# How to count all true/false c++

Tags: c++

I have some quest. Main target is count all true / false in sub-program (function)

In main() code looks like:

```
cout << Counter (true, int n);
cout << n << endl;
cout << Counter (true, int n);
cout << n << endl;
cout << Counter (false, int n);
cout << n << endl;
```

Count of true's should be returned and count of flase should be cout as "n" variable.

Now i have only

```
int Counter (bool decision, int &n){
 if (decision){
  //WHEN TRUE
 }
 else{
  //WHEN FALSE
 }
}
```

Program should out with

```
0 1 
0 2 
1 2
```

I can't modify main() Sorry for my english
Regards

Comment: As for me then I have understood nothing.:)

Comment: I have not any ide how to count true. Because i can't declarate another variable and i must count that in one variable :/

Comment: Are you sure you can't declare any other variable? What is the original assignment specification?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by making the function `Counter(bool decision, int &n)` return the number of false answers, using a static variable. Static variables are kept for the lifetime of the program.

```
int Counter(bool decision, int &n) {
    static int falseDecisionCount = 0;
    if(decision) {
        ++n;
    } else {
        ++falseDecisionCount;
    }
    return falseDecisionCount;
}
```

Since `falseDecisionCount` is static, its value won't be reset when the function is recalled.